# Counting numbers up with animation

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I want to count up a number with a animation. I have a HTML code where I set the number and a function which is counting this numbers. The problem is that I have a number `95%` with a percent character after it. But the function removes this character. Do you have any ideas why?

```js
var fired = 0;
$(document).ready(function () {
 if(fired === 0) {
  $('.count').each(function () {
   $(this).prop('Counter',0).animate({
    Counter: $(this).text()
       }, {
       duration: 3000,
       easing: 'swing',
       step: function (now) {
       $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
       }
   });
  });
  fired = 1; //Only do scroll function once
 }
});
```

```css
.count {
    font-size: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-weight: 900;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: block;
    padding-top: 15px;
}
#counter {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    width: 28.71111111%;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0 30px;
}
#counter h3 {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: 100;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="counter">
 <h3>
  <span class="count customer-satisfaction">95%</span>
  Customer Satisfaction
 </h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Add a span with % sign only.

Comment: @hunzaboy I tryed it but the problem is that the function removes this percent character ;) and when I put it outside of the span in a new one the CSS formation is missing on it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because the `$(this).text(Math.ceil(now))` clears the `<span class="count">` before inserting the number, if you tell the function to add the `%` to the number like so: `$(this).text(Math.ceil(now) + '%');` it will be like you want it.

**UPDATE from comment by OP**

Turns out the case was that there were multiple `<span class="count">` which stopped my original answer from working. By adding

```
if ($(this).hasClass('customer-satisfaction')) { 
    $(this).text(Math.ceil(now) + '%'); 
} else { 
    $(this).text(Math.ceil(now)); 
}
```

The `%` would only be added to the right number, instead of all.

```js
var fired = 0;
$(document).ready(function () {
 if(fired === 0) {
  $('.count').each(function () {
   $(this).prop('Counter',0).animate({
    Counter: $(this).text()
       }, {
           duration: 3000,
          easing: 'swing',
        step: function (now) {
        if ($(this).hasClass('customer-satisfaction')) { 
                        $(this).text(Math.ceil(now) + '%'); 
                    } else { 
                        $(this).text(Math.ceil(now)); 
                    }
       }
   });
  });
  fired = 1; //Only do scroll function once
 }
});
```

```css
.count {
    font-size: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-weight: 900;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: block;
    padding-top: 15px;
}
#counter {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    width: 28.71111111%;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0 30px;
}
#counter h3 {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: 100;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="counter">
 <h3>
  <span class="count customer-satisfaction">95%</span>
  Customer Satisfaction
 </h3>
</div>
```

Comment: but I have 3 fields which are counted but only one should contain the percent?

Comment: Ahh got it ;) `if ($(this).hasClass('customer-satisfaction')) {
                 $(this).text(Math.ceil(now) + '%');
                } else {
                 $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
                }`

Comment: There you go, hope I helped! :) @ItsOdi

Comment: Yes you helped a lot!

Answer (score 1):

CSS SOLUTION:

If you want to add them to all the counts via CSS you can do it like this:

```
.count:after{content: '%'}
```

**If you want to do it to customer-satisfaction span only,  you can do it like this:**

```
.customer-satisfaction:after{content: '%'}
```

Comment: This will add the `%` to ALL the `<span class="count">` which is not what OP is looking for.

Comment: @Simplicity, Seriously? I am sure OP understands it and will use it per his/her requirement.

Comment: If you'd take look at the comments on my answer, you'd see him saying it.